# How to trigger a button event while checked status change for checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to generate button click event while checking checkbox in data grid view. How it this possible?

I put my perform click event in `dataGridView1_CellContentClick`.

When I click on any row first time button event could not perform, however when I click other row then it will perform a button click event for first row click. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is this [wpf], [winforms], [asp.net], etc?

Comment: its window form application

Comment: Do you think that might be a relevant tag?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when anywhere in the cell is clicked, then its best to use CellClick or probably CellMouseDown.

If you are not after whitespace in the row or column then its best to use CellContentClick (for columns like checkbox, button, link etc)..